# Using custom operators in combination

Tags: swift, operators

Let's assume I have defined a prefix operator `*`, and a function associated with it:

```
prefix operator * { }
prefix func * (value: Int) -> Bool {
    return value == 5
}
```

The function returns a `Bool`, so an obvios thing to do is negating it with the `!` prefix operator.
When trying to do so, one has to use brackets though:

```
let myBool = !(*5)
```

Is there a way to use the operators together: `!*5`
without defining a new operator: `prefix operator !* { }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it's not possible. The combination of the 2 operators is seen by the compiler as a single operator, which is not recognized.

It's not even possible adding a space between the not operator and its operand, as unary operators must be "attached". So the only 2 options left are the ones you would want to avoid:

1. use parenthesis
2. define a new `!*` operator

Note that even if the compiler could be able to parse them as 2 distinct operators, it's possible that it wouldn't work. In fact, avoiding sugar syntax and using operators as normal functions, this works:

```
let bool = (*)(5)
let not = (!)(bool)
```

but this doesn't:

```
(!)(*)(5)
```

whereas making precedence explicit it works:

```
(!)((*)(5))
```